# Delphi распознавание  элементов

Tags: распознавание, delphi, алгоритм

На днях  увидел видео, решение судоку в реальном времени, через веб-камеру выполнимое на си решил попробовать нечто подобное сделать на дельфи, но в самом начале встал в ступор, не нашел документации по распознаванию элементов. Может быть что подскажите.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы про статью на Хабре, то там все пошагово было разжевано. **Независимо от языка**.

В делфи нет никаких стандартных компонентов, которые можно кинуть на форму и они распознают изображение. В первую очередь решите проблему получения данных с камеры. Потом найдите на листе саму область судоку, реализовав упомянутые в статье алгоритмы поиска линий. Когда уже есть фрагмент изображения с головоломкой, разбитый линиями, вырезайте отдельные клетки и сравнивайте картинку с образцом, чтобы определиться со значением цифры.